# change color of specific jlist elements

Tags: java, swing, jlist, renderer

I have been working on a messenger project for a while now and i need to set color of specific elements in my `JList`. I have been reading a lot on the internet but not exactly getting a simple explanation for doing so.Exactly stating my problem in this i am checking if there is an unread message from the user or not and if there is an unread message i want to do something that shows that there is a message from that particular user. What came into my mind is changing color of that element and i have not been able to understand how to do so.I have created a small executable code in which i want to change color of only those which have their flag true.Smallest code i can generate is as follows.

Can anyone please use the `ListCellRenderer` accordingly in this code so that i know how this is done.

```
    package newpackage;

    import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;


    public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public boolean f0,f1,f2,f3,f4;
/**
 * Creates new form NewJFrame
 */
public NewJFrame() {
    f1=f2=f0=true;
    f3=f4=false;
    initComponents();
    lst.setModel(addToList());
}

public DefaultListModel addToList() {
    DefaultListModel<String> dlm = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        dlm.addElement("Item"+i);
    }
    return dlm;

}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    lst = new javax.swing.JList<>();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(lst);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 117, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(277, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(36, 36, 36)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 250, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(14, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JList<String> lst;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

**EDIT 1:** Ok I read the articles and set up the custom renderer. It works as it is supposed to but not like i would want it to. In my code `setCellRenderer` method is called multiple times and everytime it is supposed to change color of different elements of the `JList` which it does just fine but i do not want the renderer to change the color of previously changed element to normal.Regenerating the problem with a short code will be difficult so i am gonna explain with a little example.Let us suppose my `JList` contains 4 elements item1,item2,item3,item4. Now first time when the `setCellRenderer` method is called it changes the color of item1 to just say green and every other element is currently black.Now `setCellRenderer` method is called again now it changes the color of element just say item3 to green and what it should not do is change the color of item1 to black again it should stay green. Can anyone please suggest a way to do that.

Comment: You need to create a custom ListCellRenderer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/. Use Jlist.setListCellRenderer(...)

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer.

Comment: @ControlAltDel can anyone please do that in this program so that i can implement that logic in my other main program. As the main reason of putting this question here was to get clarity which i think i will only get once i see all thing happening in this code.Any help will be appreciated .

Comment: Nobody is going to do your work for you. This one is pretty simple, you just need to create a class that implements the ListCellRenderer interface. Look up the API for that class (see VGR's link), it should just be one method that gives you the item that you are rendering the list cell for. You just need to return a JComponent from this method to be used as the list cell. So you can make a JPanel in there, and if there's a new message on your object change the background color of the panel, or whatever other component you wish to use.